# Doctrine does not return null for NULL values when you use get magic methods

Tags: php, null, compare, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a Symfony application configured with Doctrine, and I have designed a one-to-many relationship between two models: a `Item` belongs to a `Customer`, which is an alias for `sfGuardUser`.

Let's say that there are certain situations where an item does not have any customer. To test this I'm trying to make this comparison:

```
$customer = $this->getCustomer();
if ( $customer ) {
  return $customer->getNbInvoices();
}
else {
  return 'n/a';
}
```

However `$this->getCustomer()` does not return `null` or any other 'false' value to compare with, and the foreign key is set to NULL in the database.

How can I compare an object that does not store an actual value in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that $this->getCustomer() return a blank instance of customer doctrine_record. You can test if the customer has an ID, or you can use a method of doctrine_record class exists() :

```
if($customer->exists()){
 code...
}
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html#exists%28%29

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if ($this->relatedExists('Customer') {
   return $this['Customer']->getNbInvoices();
} else {
  return 'n/a';
}
```